# Adding active class in laravel links

Tags: laravel

If I want to add active class to `routes` I'll use:

```
class="{{ Route::currentRouteNamed('products.index') ? 'active' : '' }}"
```

If I want use it in static links I'll use:

```
class="{{ Request::is('/blog') ? 'active' : ''}}"
```

But what If I want to use it on dynamic url's? like adding custom link to my menu then I have something like:

```
@foreach($menus as $menu)
  <li class="">
    <a href="{{$menu->link}}">{{$menu->title}}</a>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

now what should i use as my `li` class in order to add active class?

Answer (score 0):

If `$menu->link` looks like `home` for example, do the same:

```
<a href="{{ $menu->link }}" {{ request()->is($menu->link) ? 'class="active"' : '' }}>{{ $menu->title }}</a>
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ')' `

Comment: doesn't work. I read something about `segment` not sure what is it!

Comment: @mafortis it depends on what exactly do you have in `$menu->link` and what your URL looks like.

Comment: @mafortis give me a real example of `$menu->link` and a real URL of the current page, please.

Comment: @mafortis you shouldn't keep full URL with `http://...` in DB. Just keep the important part, in this case, it's  `item/product-nine`. If you'll keep full URL, you'll meet a lot of problems in the future. Also, `request()->is()` will work for you if you'll just keep URI and not full URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code :

```
@foreach($menus as $menu)
  <li class="{{Request::is($menu->link) ? 'active': ''}}">
    <a href="{{$menu->link}}">{{$menu->title}}</a>
  </li>
@endforeach
```